# 'Compactness' result for independent sigma algebras

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $A, B_1, B_2, \dots \in \mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathcal{F}_n := \sigma(B_1,\dots,B_n)$ and $\mathcal{F}_\infty := \sigma(B_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$.

**Question:** If $A$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then is $A$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_\infty$?

More generally, let $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ be a filtration and $\mathcal{F}_\infty:=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_n: n \in \mathbb{N})$.

**Question:** If the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then is $\mathcal{G}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_\infty$?

---

I think that the first statement is true, but suspect that the second statement might not be true in general, but might still be true if the $\mathcal{F}_n$ are, say, finitely/countably generated.

My intution for the first statement is as follows: Given $B \in \mathcal{F}_\infty$, we can find an event $C_n \in \mathcal{F}_n$ contained in $B$ which is the 'component of $B$ in $\mathcal{F}_n$', i.e. $C_n = B \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i$. Then $A$ is independent of $C_n$ for all $n$, and by letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ and using the continuity of $\mathbb{P}$ we can recover independence between $A$ and $B$.

In the more general case, I feel that you might be able to do something similar when the $\sigma$-algebras are finitely generated. However I am unsure whether something like this would work in general. Even in the easier case, I am not entirely convinced that $C_n$ is guaranteed to be in $\mathcal{F}_n$.

Comment: The second one is also true and it is a simple application of the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah yes thank you, I should have suspected.